Prevent Firefox auto redirects to a new tab & close the old one?
I'm using Pops OS, and I'm using Firefox 130. when browsing & clicking links from Google search results. more specifically facebook links related to facebook pages. facebook redirect me to a new tab & close the old one. so I'm not able to use the back button in Firefox. so how to prevent this? please note that this doesn't happen in Google Chrome.


saw the video. It is not clear. Add original url and redirected url in the question. Mention the names of any extensions you are using in Firefox.

The video doesn't show any new tab opening, this is a confusing question. Is the login part required? Provide stepby step debug instructions.

This matches the behavior I'm seeing when using Facebook Container. What add-ons are you using?
